# How to get the records in lightning record picker based on current logged in user?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there any possiblity to get the records in lightning record picker based on current logged in user?

Comment: This question is vague and unclear. The answer assumes you mean based on ownership, but for me I immediately assumed you meant the records the current user has sharing access to. Please ensure that your question include all relevant details and avoid posting questions that show no effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`@salesforce/user/Id`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/get-current-user.html) import to get the **user ID** of the logged-in user and then you can use it as a filter criteria in the lightning record picker component.

For example, you can filter the records by the owner field the lightning record picker will only show the records that the current user owns.

Here is a sample code:

HTML::

```
<template>
        <lightning-record-picker
                object-api-name="Account"
                label="Select an account"
                onchange={handleChange}
                filter={filter}>
        </lightning-record-picker>
</template>
```

JS::

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id';

export default class RecordPickerExample extends LightningElement {
        userId = USER_ID;
        filter = {
                criteria: [{
                        fieldPath: 'OwnerId',
                        operator: 'eq',
                        value: this.userId
                }]
        };

        handleChange(event) {
                // handle record selection
        }
}
```